# What's the envelope inside mac's box?

Tags: macbook-pro

When I opened the box of my new MacBook Pro (damn it smelled so uniquely!!), below the laptop there is a black case, where the charger and another long (looped) cable (I don't know what this is suppose to do..) lie.

There is also a black packet, with the sign:

> Designed by Apple in California

Inside that, 2 booklets lie with Instructions, etc. and a black soft envelope, which is inside transparent latex(?).

What is that soft envelope for?

Comment: It comes not inside a latex one, but a vinyl envelope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The black piece of cloth is not an envelope, but a nicely folded display polishing cloth.

Apple mentions it in the manual:

> Cleaning the MacBook Pro screen
>
> To clean the MacBook Pro screen, first shut down
> your MacBook Pro and unplug the power adapter. Then dampen the **included cleaning
> cloth** with just water and wipe the screen. Do not spray liquid directly on the screen.

<sup>You can confirm the looks on [this review](https://www.pcper.com/reviews/Mobile/Apple-MacBook-Pro-23GHz-Sandy-Bridge-133-Review-2011-Model/Specifications-Packaging-I). And the long cable is just an extender which you can plug into your charger.</sup>

Comment: That's sooooo Cooo0ooo0l!!!! Great!:D