# Keyboard marks on MacBook Pro display

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard

This issue starts to annoy me too much, time is passing, I have been changing laptops and the problem persists (didn't have this issue with the old keyboards), therefore wondering if there are any accessories, covers that could help alleviate this problem.

For now, I am using a small piece of cloth but sometimes the lid doesn't close properly, it may not be the best solution but is by far less annoying to see keyboard marks in the display.

I am not an expert on fabrics but would like to know the names or properties to search for something thin and absorbent that could help also eventually to clean the display.

Any ideas, products, etc.?

[image]
[image]

Comment: If a small piece of fabric is causing your lid not to close properly, that means the tolerance is very tight between the top case and the LCD; meaning you could damage things.  However, you could try a [lens cleaning cloth](https://amzn.to/2RHPNYj) as they are super thin and super soft.

Answer (score 1):

Not an expert on fabrics either, but you can look for a thin microfibre cleaning cloth, similar to the one [bundled](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/250766/whats-the-envelope-inside-macs-box) by Apple with new Macs.

I am not sure if Apple is still bundling it with current generation of Macs.